# Github Action/Ubuntu: add to PYTHONPATH

Tags: github-actions

On Github Action workflow `main.yml`, I did the following to add to PYTHONPATH

```
PWD=$(pwd)
export PYTHONPATH=$PWD/src:$PWD/tests:$PYTHONPATH
```

I verified the PYTHONPATH using the following command

```
echo "PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH"
```

and the output is `PYTHONPATH=/home/runner/work/my_api/my_api/src:/home/runner/work/my_api/my_api/tests`

I have a module called `my_api` live under `/home/runner/work/my_api/my_api/src`

But now I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_api'` It seems export PYTHONPATH has no impact on the system. Below is the complete workfile YML file.

```
name: Integration Test Run
env:
    HISTORIC_DATA_FOLDER: /usr/my_api_historic_data
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Python 3
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: 3.6
      - name: Filessytem Setup
        run: |
          pwd
          mkdir my_api_historic_data_test
      - name: Docker Compose
        run: |
          sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-github.yml build
          sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-github.yml --verbose --env-file .env up &
      - name: Intgration Test Setup
        run: |
          echo "-----pwd-----"
          pwd

          echo "-----ls-----"
          ls

          echo "-----ls src/-----"
          ls src/

          echo "----PYTHONPATH------"
          PWD=$(pwd)
          export PYTHONPATH=$PWD/src:$PWD/tests:$PYTHONPATH
          echo "PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH"

          echo "-----HISTORIC PATH----"
          export HISTORIC_DATA_FOLDER=/home/runner/work/my_api/my_api/my_api_historic_data_test
          echo "HISTORIC_DATA_FOLDER=$HISTORIC_DATA_FOLDER"
      - name: Integreation Test Run
        run: |
          sleep 30
          pip install requests
          sudo python -m unittest discover
```

Comment: Each named part has it's own environment. You need to 'merge' 'test setup' and 'test run'.

Answer (score 4):

As already said in comments, each `step` runs in it's own shell. You need to make sure your variable is exported properly, so that it's available in all subsequent steps.

```
echo "PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

See [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) for more details.