# How to append to PYTHONPATH on a Windows runner?

Tags: powershell, github-actions

Suppose I would like to append a relative path, e.g. `.\src`, to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable on a `windows-latest` hosted runner in GitHub Actions.

For the updated environment variable to be available in subsequent steps, we need to add it to the `GITHUB_ENV` environment file, as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70419338):

> You can make an environment variable available to any subsequent steps in a workflow job by defining or updating the environment variable and writing this to the `GITHUB_ENV` environment file. The step that creates or updates the environment variable does not have access to the new value, but all subsequent steps in a job will have access.

However, reading the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) on a Linux system I only see an example for `bash`:

```bash
echo "{environment_variable_name}={value}" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```

It is not immediately obvious to me how to translate this to PowerShell, which is the [default shell on a Windows runner](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell).

I would expect some way to switch the documentation from bash to PowerShell, but don't see it.

Alternatively I could tell the workflow step to use `shell: bash`, but that's just confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me attempt a **pragmatic summary**, based on the following documentation links you have found yourself:

- The [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].shell`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell) setting for overriding the platform's default shell; the linked page indicates that the *default* shell on *Windows* is `pwsh`.
- Using [environment files](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions?tool=powershell#environment-files), specifically the one for defining environment *variables*, whose path the `GITHUB_ENV` environment variable (accessible as `$env:GITHUB_ENV` in PowerShell) points to.

---

- **If your [runner](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#runners) is using [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** (the modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand PowerShell edition):

  - This applies if you're using the *default* shell or - equivalently - have specified `pwsh` *and* one of the following conditions is true:

    - either: (a) you're using a [*GitHub-hosted*](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners) runner
    - or: (b) you're using a [*self-hosted*](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners) runner *and you have PowerShell 7+ installed and `pwsh.exe` is discoverable via `$env:PATH`*.
  - Use of **`>>` is sufficient** - in PowerShell 7+, it uses (BOM-less) UTF-8, as required:

    ```
    "PYTHONPATH=$env:PYTHONPATH;.\src" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV
    ```
- **If your runner is using *Windows PowerShell*** (the legacy, Windows-only edition that comes with Windows; the GitHub docs call it "PowerShell Desktop"):

  - This applies:

    - either (a): if you have specified `powershell` explicitly.
    - or (b) if you're using the *default* shell or - equivalently - `pwsh` in a *self-hosted* runner in which `pwsh.exe`, the PowerShell (Core) 7+ CLI, isn't discoverable via `$env:PATH`, in which case Windows PowerShell (`powershell.exe`) is the *fallback*.
  - **Pipe to `Add-Content -Encoding utf8`**: (`>>` is *not* an option, because in Windows PowerShell it appends *UTF-16LE*-encoded ("Unicode") text):

    ```
    "PYTHONPATH=$env:PYTHONPATH;.\src" | Add-Content -Encoding utf8 -LiteralPath $env:GITHUB_ENV
    ```
  - **Caveat**:

    - This **assumes that the target file *already exists* and is *non-empty*.**
    - If this assumption doesn't hold, use the following to ensure that the file is created / filled with UTF-8-encoded text *without a BOM*:

      ```
        if (Get-Content -ErrorAction Ignore -Raw -LiteralPath $env:GITHUB_ENV) {
          "PYTHONPATH=$env:PYTHONPATH;.\src" | Add-Content -Encoding utf8 -LiteralPath $env:GITHUB_ENV 
        } else { # file doesn't exist yet or is empty.
          $null = New-Item -Force $env:GITHUB_ENV -Value "PYTHONPATH=$env:PYTHONPATH;.\src`n"
        }
      ```

---

###### Background information on character encodings when using PowerShell's `>>` redirection / `Out-File` cmdlet with `-Append`:

- The `>>` [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) operator has the same effect as piping to [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file)  `-Append ...`.

  - However, a general caveat in *Windows PowerShell*  is that `>` and `>>` blindly write / append *UTF-16LE*-encoded ("Unicode") text, which may be undesired in general and with `>>` can corrupt a differently encoded file - as would happen with `$env:GITHUB_ENV`, which expects *UTF-8*-encoded content.
  - File corruption is far less likely to occur in ([*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), which now - fortunately, consistently - defaults to *(BOM-less) UTF-8*).
- While `Add-Content` *mostly* avoids this problem, because it tries to match the existing encoding, there can still be problems when adding to a UTF-8-encoded file in *Windows PowerShell*:

  - `Add-Content` in Windows PowerShell assumes *ANSI* encoding rather than UTF-8 in the absence of a BOM in a preexisting file's content, so that any non-ASCII characters in the new content will be encoded incorrectly.

    - PowerShell 7+ now assumes UTF-8, its consistent default.
  - If you try to fix this by using an `-Encoding utf8` argument, but the target file *doesn't exist yet* or *is empty* (0 bytes), `Add-Content` *in Windows PowerShell* creates a UTF-8 file *with a BOM*, which is typically undesired.

    - In PowerShell 7+ this problem wouldn't arise, given that (a) (a) BOM-less UTF-8 is the consistent *default* and even explicit use of `-Encoding utf8` now create a *BOM-less* UTF-8 (creating one *with* a BOM requires opt-in via `-Encoding utf8bom`).
- In Windows PowerShell, using `Out-File -Append -Encoding utf8` suffers the same problem as `Add-Content -Encoding utf8` with respect to creating a UTF-8 file *with a BOM* if the target file happens to not exist yet or happens to be empty.
- In Windows PowerShell, short of using .NET APIs directly, the only way to create *BOM-less* UTF-8 files is - curiously - via [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item), as shown above.

  - Since `New-Item` doesn't automatically append a *newline* to the text passed to `-Value`, one is explicitly appended above, using `` "`n" `` (to use a *platform-native* newline, use `"$([Environment]::NewLine)"`, but it shouldn't matter).
- For general information about character encoding in the two PowerShell editions, including about the *inconsistent* defaults across cmdlets in *Windows PowerShell*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375).

Answer (score 2):

*It turns out we can switch the GitHub documentation between `Bash` and `PowerShell` [at the very top of the Workflow Commands page](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions).*

The GitHub [documentation suggests the following solution](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions?tool=powershell#setting-an-environment-variable) for PowerShell:

```
"{environment_variable_name}={value}" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_ENV -Append
```

In our case that would become:

```
"PYTHONPATH=$Env:PYTHONPATH;.\src" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_ENV -Append
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71579543), here's another way to do it:

```
Add-Content -Path $Env:GITHUB_ENV -Value "PYTHONPATH=$Env:PYTHONPATH;.\src"
```

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for these valuable insights. [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell) mention that the default shell on windows (`pwsh`) is actually PowerShell Core, and `$PSVersionTable` on a `windows-latest` runner shows it to be version 7.

Comment: Apparently the encoding caveat is also mentioned in the docs, [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions?tool=powershell#environment-files).